# afterAjaxUpdate call not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I had a similar problem as [afterAjaxUpdate callbackfunction CListView shows undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960829/afterajaxupdate-callbackfunction-clistview-shows-undefined).

Currently though my function isn't called. Really not sure why. Chrome shows no errors in the log.

I have the following in my HTML. And I can call it from the console log ok.

```
<script>
function savedUser()
{
    alert('hello');
}
</script>
```

And i'm using the following in my CGridView

```
'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'savedUser',
```

I feel that this is really obvious. But I've run out of ideas. Any help would be great

Comment: I just made a try and it worked fine. Can you view source HTML and looking for something such as jQuery('#my_grid').yiiGridView( ... 'afterAjaxUpdate':savedUser}) to see whether it existed or not?

Comment: @TelvinNguyen Didn't get afterAjaxUpdate as expected. It is down as `'afterAjaxUpdate':function() {...
` That's just a series of statements like `jQuery('.popover').remove();
`

Comment: 'afterAjaxUpdate':savedUser should have to be there. I think it's important clue to indicate your problem. Just a guess, the grid which you are reviewing and the grid which has above setting are one?

Comment: @TelvinNguyen That was it! I have several grids and I have ways of moving items between grids and I had the function in the wrong place. Thanks Telvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Yii that `'savedUser'` is the name of a JavaScript identifier so that it does not encode it -- otherwise, Yii will place quotes around `savedUser` and JavaScript will treat it as a string instead of the name of a function.

You can do this by wrapping the name in a [`CJavaScriptExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScriptExpression):

```
'afterAjaxUpdate'=> new CJavaScriptExpression('savedUser'),
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It doesn't seem to have fixed the problem though. Still nothing happens.

Comment: @Jonnny: That's strange. What does the browser's javascript console say? Any errors?

Comment: I thought so, no, no errors either. I just replied to @Telvin with his question. I know that in the docs afterAjaxUpdate expects `function(id, data) where 'id' refers to the ID of the grid view, 'data' the received ajax response data.`. But having seen the earlier Q on here I thought my way would be fine also.